# React Router with a base path

Tags: react-router, webpack-dev-server

I would like to add "/app" as my base path for all routes in react routes. So I am trying -

.... more routes

I am unable to make webpack dev server serve pages with URL localhost:8080/app. It gives me a "Cannot get /app" error. If I try localhost:8080/ - it gives me an error that it cannot match a route with "/".

What should be a basic webpack dev server configuration for this scenario?

Comment: I too would like a solution for this and struggle to understand why it would be so hard.

Answer (score 0):

The Webpack [`historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback) config option is what you're looking for. Just set that to `true` and all requests that don't route to an asset will be rewritten to `/`. You can also pass in an object with custom rewrites:

```
historyApiFallback: {
  rewrites: [
    { from: /^\/$/, to: '/views/landing.html' },
    { from: /^\/subpage/, to: '/views/subpage.html' },
    { from: /./, to: '/views/404.html' }
  ]
}
```

(Example taken from the documentation page linked above.)